# Matlab: creating a plot of a variable depending on one parameter

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math

I have a 3x3 matrix in which some elements depend on a parameter called x which can attain values between 0 and 1.
I multiply the inverse of this matrix by a 3x1 vector, and I therefore obtain a 3x1 vector  called `optimal taxes`in which each element depends on `x`.
I then create a variable called `reinf` which is equal to the first element of `optimal taxes` minus the other two elements.

I would like to plot the values of `reinf` depending on the parameter x in a range between 0 and 1.
I have tried used the following code, where `H_V1x` is the 3x3 matrix.

```
syms x positive real
optimal_taxes1x = inv(H_V1x)*inc_cons
reinf1x = optimal_taxes1x(1,1) - optimal_taxes1x(2,1) - optimal_taxes1x(3,1)
```

However when I run the last line it says I get the error "Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1)."
which is surprising since optimal_taxes1x is a 3x1 syms vector.
How could I solve this problem and create the plot?
Thank you

As requested, here are the matrix and the vector:

```
H_V1x = [  -5.9280e-07, 3.7066e-07,2.2215e-07; 3.7066e-07,(1537*x)/258614388 - 6736739427183417/2361183241434822606848,-(1537*x)/258614388;2.2215e-07,-(1537*x)/258614388,(1537*x)/258614388 - 6645950193052613/4722366482869645213696];

inc_cons = [0.823603356515493,
           -0.219495869657492,
           -0.0752767166225879]
```

Comment: Don’t use symbolic functions for this. It’s a numeric problem, implement it as such.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I used symbolic functions because I want to keep x as a parameter and I want my results (reinf1x) to be a function of that parameter. If there is another way to do so without using syms I would be happy to follow it.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html

Comment: I can't reproduce the error for some random `H_V1x` and `inc_cons`s. Please provide the values with which the code execution fails.

Comment: Added them now @saastn

Answer (score 1):

I can run the code with no problem in 2016b. Here is my code:

```
clear variables; clc; close all
syms x real
assume(x > 0)
H_V1x = [  -5.9280e-07, 3.7066e-07,2.2215e-07; 3.7066e-07,(1537*x)/258614388 - 6736739427183417/2361183241434822606848,-(1537*x)/258614388;2.2215e-07,-(1537*x)/258614388,(1537*x)/258614388 - 6645950193052613/4722366482869645213696];

inc_cons = [0.823603356515493;
           -0.219495869657492;
           -0.0752767166225879]

optimal_taxes1x = inv(H_V1x)*inc_cons;
reinf1x = optimal_taxes1x(1,1) - optimal_taxes1x(2,1) - optimal_taxes1x(3,1)

x=0:0.02:1;
plot(x, subs(reinf1x))
```

And this is the plot result:

[image]

> reinf1x =
>
> (1040053994187210661864407040*(495592707753015189241062869767647395840*x - 89156821447333517620228626174465662937))/(747*(2815381160608336475815926275042762431495254208116923826176*x - 445811259036595286456502337342890549874079624653932849201)) - (460318575875822254261534720*(11210459727128231750210203484711869743104*x - 2497571854516097684109652531721363759511))/(30627*(2815381160608336475815926275042762431495254208116923826176*x - 445811259036595286456502337342890549874079624653932849201)) - (42633524607347156989247488*(162551666043359360378047950528322111275008*x - 3799129388554029548248573922328032752851))/(30627*(2815381160608336475815926275042762431495254208116923826176*x - 445811259036595286456502337342890549874079624653932849201)) - (7258277284170644693450752*(81275833021679680189023975264161055637504*x - 35848130569758668835608493944994001436187))/(10209*(2815381160608336475815926275042762431495254208116923826176*x - 445811259036595286456502337342890549874079624653932849201)) + (402307845408630815045189632*(495592707753015189241062869767647395840*x - 73377230813429148255176338884456817971))/(249*(2815381160608336475815926275042762431495254208116923826176*x - 445811259036595286456502337342890549874079624653932849201)) - (7623637334217303404343984128*(18254049353170950597767874357190897696768*x - 2894673088146242304784596506648828329737))/(30627*(2815381160608336475815926275042762431495254208116923826176*x - 445811259036595286456502337342890549874079624653932849201))

Comment: I have cleared everything and did it again but it still gives me the same error. Even when I try accessing H_V1x and visualise its content, it gives me a 3x3 matrix (as expected) but with all elements equal to 1x1 sym. If I double click on one element it says "error(message('symbolic:catenate:dimensionMismatch'));"
Maybe this has something to do with my error

Comment: @Vincenzoalfano I believe it does. Have you tried running very same code as mine? I mean just copy it from my post and paste it in a new script file. If the problem persists, try removing rows or columns from `H_V1x ` and check if you can access its elements by direct indexing, e.g. `disp(H_V1x (1, 1))`.

Comment: Yes, even in a new script file your code does not work. However when I make `H_V1x` a 2x2 matrix and `inc_cons` a 2x1 vector everything works fine. What could be the reason of this? And how could I solve it

Comment: @Vincenzoalfano I really don't know! I think the error will appear again if you remove rows or columns other than the ones you've already removed. If this is the case, try to find the exact element that corrupts the matrix. That way you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Actually I have tried running my code again and now it works, so thank you for your help! :)

Comment: I'm glad it finally worked. Things like this are really nightmares!